# Audio from url not playing completely

Tags: c#, audio, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to add text to speech to my project in Unity 5.4.4f, and I am using an API that allows me to enter in what to say in the url bar then it return an audio file, which I download and play.

```
Regex rgx = new Regex("\\s+");
string result = rgx.Replace(timeLeft + " minutes left", "+");
string url = "http://api.voicerss.org/?key=MY_API_KEY&hl=en-us&src=" + result;
Debug.Log(url);
WWW audioWWW = new WWW(url);
yield return audioWWW;
AudioClip audClip = audioWWW.GetAudioClip(false, false, AudioType.MPEG);
audSrc.clip = audClip;
audSrc.Play();
```

It plays the audio for 1 second then stops.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34042928/how-to-stream-downloadplay-an-audio-from-url) might be useful.

Comment: I had already seen that post and tried it, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server you are using generates *.mp3* file and that file seems to be compressed. The problem of not being able to finish playing the audio or just playing one second of it only happens with this file.

The fix is to use `GetAudioClipCompressed` which doesn't seem to be documented yet. Just replace  `GetAudioClip` with `GetAudioClipCompressed` and pass in 2 parameters to it.

```
public static AudioClip GetAudioClipCompressed(this WWW www, bool threeD, AudioType audioType);
```

The audio was able to play after doing this. Here is what the complete code looks like. Note that I removed the API key. You can put that on your own.

```
IEnumerator Start()
{
    Regex rgx = new Regex("\\s+");
    string result = rgx.Replace(timeLeft + " minutes left", "+");
    string url = "http://api.voicerss.org/?key=MY_API_KEY&hl=en-us&src=" + result;
    Debug.Log(url);
    WWW audioWWW = new WWW(url);
    yield return audioWWW;
    AudioClip audClip = audioWWW.GetAudioClipCompressed(false, AudioType.MPEG);
    audSrc.clip = audClip;
    audSrc.Play();
}
```